# php array code with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

there are few mistakes which it is showing as

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in array 4,9,10,11,12... can anyone resolve them

```
<?PHP

$hosts = array(
array("ronmexico.kainalopallo.com/","beforename=$F_firstname%20$F_lastname&gender=$F_gender","Your Ron Mexico Name is ","/the ultimate disguise, is <u><b>([^<]+)<\/b><\/u>/s"),
array("www.fjordstone.com/cgi-bin/png.pl","gender=$F_gender&submit=Name%20Me","Your Pagan name is ","/COLOR=#000000 SIZE=6> *([^<]*)<\/FONT>/"),
array("rumandmonkey.com/widgets/toys/mormon/index.php","gender=$F_gender&firstname=$F_firstname&surname=$F_lastname","Your Mormon Name is ","/<p>My Mormon name is <b>([^<]+)<\/b>!<br \/>/s"),
array("cyborg.namedecoder.com/index.php","acronym=$F_firstname&design=edox&design_click-edox.x=0&design_click-edox.y=0&design_click-edox=edo","","Your Cyborg Name is ","/<p>([^<]+)<\/p>/"),
array("rumandmonkey.com/widgets/toys/namegen/10/","nametype=$brit&page=2&id=10&submit=God%20save%20the%20Queen!&name=$F_firstname%20$F_lastname","Your Very British Name is ","/My very British name is \&lt\;b\&gt;([^&]+)\&lt;\/b\&gt;\.\&lt;br/"),
array("blazonry.com/name_generator/usname.php","realname=$F_firstname+$F_lastname&gender=$F_gender","Your U.S. Name is ","/also be known as <font size=\'\+1\'><b>([^<]+)<\/b>/s"),
array("www.spacepirate.org/rogues.php","realname=$F_firstname%20$F_lastname&formentered=Yes&submit=Arrrgh","Your Space Pirate name is ","/Your pirate name is <font size=\'\+1\'><b>([^<]+)<\/b><\/font>/s"),
array("rumandmonkey.com/widgets/toys/ghetto/","firstname=$F_firstname&lastname=$F_lastname","Your Ghetto Name is ","/<p align=\"center\" style=\"font-size: 36px\">\s*<br \/>\s*([^<]*)<br \/>/"),
array("www.emmadavies.net/vampire/default.aspx","mf=$emgender&firstname=$F_firstname&lastname=$F_lastname&submit=Find+My+Vampire+Name","","Your Vampire Name is ","/<i class=\"vampirecontrol vampire name\">([^<]*)<\/i>/"),
array("www.emmadavies.net/fairy/default.aspx","mf=$emgender&firstname=$F_firstname&lastname=$F_lastname&submit=Seek+Fairy","","Your Fairy Name is ","/<i class=\'ng fairy name\'>([^<]*)<\/i>/"),
array("www.irielion.com/israel/reggaename.html","phase=3&oldname=$F_firstname%20$F_lastname&gndr=$reggender","","Your Rasta Name is ","/Yes I, your irie new name is ([^\n]*)\n/"),
array("www.ninjaburger.com/fun/games/ninjaname/ninjaname.php","realname=$F_firstname+$F_lastname","Your Ninja Burger Name is ","/<BR>Ninja Burger ninja name will be<BR><BR><FONT SIZE=\'\+1\'>([^<]*)<\/FONT>/"),
array("gangstaname.com/pirate_name.php","sex=$F_gender&name=$F_firstname+$F_lastname","Your Pirate Name is ","/<p><strong>We\'ll now call ye:<\/strong><\/p> *<h2 class=\"newName\">([^<]*)<\/h2>/"),
array("www.xach.com/nerd-name/","name=$F_firstname+$F_lastname&gender=$F_gender","Your Nerd Name is ","/<p><div align=center class=\"nerdname\">([^<]*)<\/div>/"),
array("rumandmonkey.com/widgets/toys/namegen/5941/","page=2&id=5941&nametype=$dj&name=$F_firstname+$F_lastname","Your DJ Name is ","/My disk spinnin nu name is &lt\;b&gt\;([^<]*)&lt\;\/b&gt\;\./"),
array("pizza.sandwich.net/poke/pokecgi.cgi","name=$F_firstname%20$F_lastname&color=black&submit=%20send%20","Your Pokename is ","/Your Pok&eacute;name is: <h1>([^<]*)<\/h1>/")
);

return $hosts;

?>
```

Comment: My eyes!! my eyes!!

Comment: it's not our job to do your job.

Comment: What in the name of all things holy is this code doing and why?  I mean, I see the whole "building a 2-dimensional array of strings" part, but I'd like you to make sense of it for me.

Comment: Also, where does preg_match() even come into this?  I see some attempts at regular expression syntax, but I don't see it being used.  (Also, side note, props for the Ninja Burger links.  I have the card game, it's pretty fun.)

Comment: Obviously it's data for a page which accepts several parameters (firstname, lastname, gender), then goes to various pages (array[0]), passes parameters to them (array[1]) and tries to scrape the results using a regexp (array[2]) so you can gather a super cool list of "Your X Name".  ;P

Comment: Please be more _____ when you ask a _____, Fill in the blanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: preg_match()
>   [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must
>   not be alphanumeric or backslash in
>   array 4,9,10,11,12

That means that PCRE had problems compiling your regexes. Those are not PHP warnings, but they are dfasd jf AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGH nooooo! Mommy dsfjjasdfasds

sfdkjsd
dsklf
uio

Answer (score 2):

Completely unreadable. If you want help, please isolate your code and ask a precise question. Nobody will troubleshoot a mess like this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a questionable escaping at each of those indexes in your regular expression, specifically with respect to:

1. \;
2. \'
3. \n